# why cannot access to contiguous memory addresses in physical memory

Tags: memory, architecture, operating-system, virtual-memory

According to Microsoft documentation in the following link :

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
>
> - A program can use a contiguous range of virtual addresses to access a
>   large memory buffer that is not contiguous in physical memory.

So there's a question,that why in physical memory cannot have contiguous memory for a process?

Also there's another question due to the documentation, the following picture which demonstrates virtual memory for user and system space:

[image]

The system virtual address space is unique in the whole of the memory but there's a virtual address space for each process ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes but few months ago, sorry about this

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Could you do a favor ? I didn't find anything about what you said.If you don't mind show me at least in the page that the reason has been mentioned. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first when a process is loaded into memory, the OS can optimize to load process pages contiguously to physical memory.The process pages in memory cant always be contiguous due to swapping in and out, because there are other processes and things in memory that occupy space,so if later when some process pages becomes less used it is swapped back to hard drive, and when it is needed again it is not guaranteed to be loaded to the same spot before swapping out because there can be another process page laying there. You should read about virtual memory to gain good understanding of all of this.

Comment: Could you add some more explanation about the second  question ? thanks

Comment: @Mohammadyummy ,yes kernel has its own virtual space, and user processes each have their own virtual space.Each process is isolated from each other and process A can't access process B address space unless process B let's to do so in case of inter-process communication

Answer (score -3):

You'r Questionn is simple!you have asked why we can have large memory buffer in virtual memory but not in physical one! thats because we are limited to the hardware!if we were able to access as much as buffer we want on our physical memory,industries had to make like 1024GB memories for our satisfaction! but we are using 8GB memory and we are satisfy...!virtual memories exist to satisfy our needs and make hardwares much more efficient!

hope it helps <3

Comment: I didn't downvote but your answer made no sense at all and doesn't appear to answer the question.